# Flutter не работает фильтрация девайсов через манифест/uses-feature

Tags: android, flutter

В **PlayMarket** некоторые устройства не могут скачать приложение.

загруженный бандл в гугл консоль пишет , что многие устройства не поддерживаются тк

> Не поддерживает требуемые функции: android.hardware.camera.autofocus

в манифесте проекта я прописал

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

и после повторной сборки и загрузки бандла ничего не меняется , кол-во поддерживаемых устройств остается тем же , а если зайти в не поддерживаемый девайс пишет всё тоже уведомление

пробовал разные комбинации , убирал `android.hardware.camera` и прописывал ей `android:required="false"`

Comment: Где список использованных библиотек? Или гадать будем?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />`

Comment: использованные библиотеки 

 shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter_statusbarcolor: ^0.2.3
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  flutter_qr_reader: ^1.0.3
  camera: ^0.5.8+5
  permission_handler: ^3.0.1

Comment: @MiT  список поддерживаемых устройств стал еще меньше =)

Comment: 1)flutter_qr_reader замените на что-то нормальное (он слишком много использует разрешений). 2)В манифесте просто так не пишите, если плагины не требуют в инструкциях (в новых версиях манифет можно настраивать из плагина). 3)Чем больше разрешений тем меньше устройств.